# Creating an object of a class with constructor that throws

Tags: c++, exception, c++11

I am learning exceptions.. The aim of the sample code is to create a proper object.
Here it goes...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

using std::string;
using std::invalid_argument;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Person
{
public:
    Person(){}
    Person(string name, int age)
    {
        if (age < 18)
            throw invalid_argument(name + " is minor!!!");
        if (name.empty())
            throw invalid_argument("Name can't be empty");
        _name = name;
        _age = age;
    }
    Person(Person&& that) : _name(std::move(that._name))
    {
        _age = that._age;
        that._name.clear();
    }
    Person& operator=(Person&& that)
    {
        _name = std::move(that._name);
        _age = that._age;
        that._name.clear();
        return *this;
    }

    Person(const Person& that)
    {
        _age = that._age;
        _name = that._name;
    }
    Person& operator=(const Person& that)
    {
        _name = that._name;
        _age = that._age;
        return *this;
    }

    ~Person() { cout << "In person destructor"; }
    string getName(void) const { return _name; }
private:
    string _name;
    int _age;
};

Person createPerson()
{
    try
    {
        string name;
        int age;
        cout << "Enter name of the person: ";
        cin >> name;
        cout << "Enter age of the person: ";
        cin >> age;
        Person aNewPerson(name, age);
        return aNewPerson;
    }
    catch (invalid_argument& e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
        cout << "Please try again!!!" << endl;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    Person aNewPerson;

    aNewPerson = createPerson();

    cout << aNewPerson.getName() << " created" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I want to exit the program only when the proper object is constructed. 
Say for example if I enter name as APerson and age as 1, an exception is thrown.
But, I want to continue the process of creating an object and exit the program only after successful creation of object.

I am not getting how to do.
Can someone help?
Thanks.

Comment: In order to do something an indefinite number of times, you're going to need some sort of loop.

Comment: That's correct. Also, Am I handling the exception at the right place? cos' the createPerson() doesn't return anything if the constructor throws and exception. I am not getting how to go ahead...

Comment: You need to add the loop first. If CreatePerson won't magically fix itself by then, you are probably adding the loop to a wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got the answer, please correct me if I am wrong...
I modified the createPerson() function like this...

```
Person createPerson()
{
    while (1)
    {
        try
        {
            string name;
            int age;
            cout << "Enter name of the person: ";
            cin >> name;
            cout << "Enter age of the person: ";
            cin >> age;
            Person aNewPerson(name, age);
            return aNewPerson;
        }
        catch (invalid_argument& e)
        {
            cout << e.what() << endl;
            cout << "Please try again!!!" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's correct. One thing that you could change is puttying the try after `cin >> age;` and before the `Person` constructor in order to visualize better where the exception can happen.